# Karate testcases for fetch and update service

Tags: karate

I have one feature file to test one api. Like that I have bunch of feature files. Each api have multiple operations. Those operations are broadly classified as Get/fetch kind of operations and update/post kind of operations. In dev or uat , I don't have any concern on running test against all operations. But when it comes to production, i suppose not to test update kind of operations which will make changes in prod data. How can we classify those scenarios alone and not to test in prod.

Or how can we classify fetch alone test scenarios to test in prod.

Please help me on this

Comment: tags. you are looking for tags: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+tags

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PeterThomas Already i have two tags called smoke and regression with each scenarios. If suppose i create integration tag for prod. Is it possible to put two tags (integration and smoke) for 1 scenorio. If so is it work like or condition or and condition

Comment: yes. please read some of the answers in my previous link also: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#tags

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#environment-tags this link helped for my requirement. Added tags like `@smoke @env=prod` just before my scenorio. Then executed cmd like `java -cp some-jar-with-depenencies:. -jar some-jar-with-depenencies.jar *.feature -t @env=prod @smoke -e prod`

Comment: Even above solution is not perfect for my condition.. means the scenorios tagged `env=prod` are not getting executed for uat env.. it is executed only in prod env.. How to execute scenario for "uat&prod" and "uat only" using tags...

Comment: it is possible in karate. if you can't find this in all the links I provided above, kindly assume that karate can't support what you want and look for another tool, thanks